# Origin of "go into hock"

Tags: etymology

> We will have to *go into hock* to buy a house.

What is the origin of the idiom?

Comment: Have you looked up the word _hock_? What did you find out about it?

Comment: _Hock_ is a synonym for _pawn_. A _hock shop_ is a pawnshop, an object that's _in hock_ means it's pawned, and if you're _in hock to `P`_ then you owe `P` some money. The origin is Dutch, as @tchrist points out below.

Comment: [General Reference](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hock) **hock** *from Dutch hok "jail, pen, doghouse, hutch, hovel."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of the word is Dutch.  The origin of the phrase is American.

Per the OED, the noun ***hock*** means:

> Etymology: a. Dutch *hok* hutch, hovel, prison, (slang) credit, debt.
>
> - **a.** Phr. ***in* (occas. *the*) *hock***: (a). in the act (of gambling); (b). in prison; (c). in pawn; (d). in debt. So occas. ***out of hock***.
> - **b.** *attrib*. and *Comb*., as ***hock-game*** (see quot. 1859); ***hock-shop***, a pawnshop.

There is also an associated verb *hock*, which means *pawn*.

Comment: That's odd, because the Dutch word _hok_ actually doesn't mean that at all. It can be shed, shack, kennel, coop, closet, cabin, booth, sty, cot.

Comment: @MrLister Hutch or hovel doesn’t seem too far from cabin or shack, no?  I don’t know if the “(slang) credit, debt” is meant to be Dutch slang from some previous era, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this explanation.

**IN HOCK** Meaning: Broke; have all of your belongings in a pawn shop Origin: Comes from the Old West. In a common gambling card game called “faro,” “the last card [to be played] was called the **hocketty** card. It was said to **be in hocketty** or **in hock**. When a player bet on a card that ended up in hock he was himself in hock, at risk of losing his bets.” (From The Whole Ball of Wax, by Laurence Urdang).